# SQL Server : duplicate rows with ID < 0 and get new created ID

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have recovered a table from MS Access inside SQL Server 2008 R2.

The old table in MS Access was using a PK with replication type integer (so there's negative values)

After importing the table into SQL Server 2008 R2, I have changed the PK for an integer identity column.

What I'm trying to do now is to make a script that will take all the row with negative PK, duplicate that row with a new PK (autonumber) and change the value of other table FK (negative values) with the newly created PK (autonumber). Then, finally, delete the OLD row that was just duplicate.

Thanks for the help

This is an example of the table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TESTCopy](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Field1] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
[Field2] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
[Field3] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TESTCopy] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: There is no need to change the negative numbers. The value of a PK has **no** meaning at all. -376437 is just as good for a PK as 369838

Comment: What is your question? (You said you were trying something. So how did you try, what happened, and what are the problems?)

Comment: Well, I need them to be positive for something that I need to do later. As for the "problem", sorry I had no problem yet ... I was just not sure what to begin with ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a cursor, but they are frowned upon for performance and other issues:

```
DECLARE @CurrentID INT
DECLARE @NewID INT
DECLARE @Field1 NCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Field2 NCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Field3 NCHAR(10)

DECLARE curUpdateKeys CURSOR FOR
                    SELECT ID, Field1, Field2, Field3
                    FROM dbo.TESTCopy
                    WHERE ID < 0

OPEN curUpdateKeys

FETCH NEXT FROM curUpdateKeys INTO @CurrentID, @Field1, @Field2, @Field3

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

-- Add new record
    INSERT INTO dbo.TESTCopy
        (Field1, Field2, Field3)
    VALUES 
        (@Field1, @Field2, @Field3)
-- Capture new record ID
    SET @NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()


-- Update your foreign keyed tables with new record ID
-- Repeat for every table
    UPDATE dbo.FK_TABLES
        SET fkTESTCopyID = @NewID
    WHERE dbo.FK_TABLES.fkTESTCopyID = @CurrentID

-- Remove original row with negative record ID ID
    DELETE
    FROM dbo.TESTCopy
    WHERE ID = @CurrentID

    FETCH NEXT FROM curUpdateKeys INTO @CurrentID, @Field1, @Field2, @Field3
END

CLOSE curUpdateKeys
DEALLOCATE curUpdateKeys
```

Comment: [Well, a cursor that uses the default options is *certainly* frowned upon](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options). Also, you should look at [the OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) - it can eliminate the need for this cursor altogether.

Comment: TY for the links, especially the OUTPUT clause.  For one time maint purposes I have not had any real problems with cursors, but I do not put them in anything for regular/production use.